# Additional executable file disappears from output directory when starting from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've got 2 projects in my solution: "MainProject" and "LibraryProject". "LibraryProject" contains an additional executable which is set to "Build Action: None" and "Copy to Output Directory: Copy always". This file is essentially an external server component which is started by a class in "LibraryProject".

Now when I build the solution I got MainProject.exe, LibraryProject.dll and Server.exe in my output directory. This means the build process is working fine.

If I run it directly from the output folder it works perfectly. But if I run it via "Debug->Start Debugging" in Visual Studio the Server.exe is removed from the output directory which leads to a FileNotFoundException in my application. It doesn't matter if I use the "Release" or "Debug" configuration.

Some additional information: Visual Studio 2015 Professional, "MainProject" is set to "Windows Application" and is a WPF project. "LibraryProject" is set to "Class Library". "Project->Add Reference->Projects->Solution->LibraryProject" was used to add the library to the main project. Yes i tried "Clean Solution" and "Rebuild Solution".

Answer (score 0):

I've now got a solution which raises more questions than it answers:

When i remove the NuGet package Lz4.Net (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lz4.Net/) everything works fine. I now replaced it with lz4net (https://www.nuget.org/packages/lz4net/) and the problem is gone without losing functionality.

As for why this happens, I got no idea.